# jQuery on click toggles DIV in a list and only ever show one at a time, and same div on .dblclick() use different toggle?

Tags: jquery

I have a horizontal list of covers, if you click any of them it will toggle and reveal the back, but only one toggles at a time. But if you double click the front cover it also toggles to reveal a different back.

The first toggle works, with only one being shown at a time.  But the second toggle on `dblClick` doesn't work.  I'm not sure if I need to write the first toggle better using `onClick` explicitly or if the second toggle is impossible anyway?

The HTML

```
    <div id="cover-wrapper">
      <ul class="covers">
        <li class="cover" id="remove-cover">
            <div class="cover-front">
        <a href="javascript:showonlyone('show-back1');" >
               <img src="images/covers/1.png" />
            </a>
            </div>    
            <div class="cover-back" id="show-back1">
              <div class="content">
                 <!-- content here...  -->
              </div>
            </div>       
       </li>
       <li class="cover" id="remove-cover">
            <div class="cover-front">
        <a href="javascript:showonlyone('show-back2');" >
               <img src="images/covers/2.png" />
            </a>
            </div>    
            <div class="cover-back" id="show-back2">
              <div class="content">
                <!-- content here...  -->
              </div>
            </div>       
      </li>
```

Javascript

```
//Toggle cover on click from front to back & only ever show one toggled from list
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
  $(".cover-back").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
      $(this).fadeIn(0);
    } else {
      $(this).fadeOut(0);
    }
  }
});

//Toggle cover on dblclick from front to back with different back div 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li.cover").dblclick(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("cover-back-2")) {
      $(this).toggleClass("cover-back-2", false);
    } else {
      $(this).toggleClass("cover-back-2", true);
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: the hasClass then toggle class seems redundant, can't the whole if statement turn into a single $(this).toggleClass("cover-back-2") ?  Can you also create a fiddle using a sample image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified your code to

http://jsfiddle.net/HkwTg/1/

The toggleClass works on double click, you can see it in firebug, i edited it so the text turns to green. You should handle the single click in jquery

Comment: Not sure why you removed the first image from the original HTML. If you need sample images you can use `<img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x100" />` placeholder.it is great for that, just specify any size you want in the url to get that image placeholder.

Comment: Yea I need a placeholder and also having the image or not makes no difference on testing if double clicks works or not

Comment: Thanks for the image placeholder link, very helfpful!